# Content in div shows outside of border in safari

Tags: javascript, html, css, safari

I keep getting this problem with my code, when it is looking ok in Chrome it won't look the same in Safari. I use Safari 9.1. The content, in this case right aligned text is the whole time outside the border.

I hope someone can maybe help me.

**Example:**

**- Safari:**

[image]

**- Chrome:**

[image]

```
#date{
    border: 1px solid red;
    position:absolute;
    text-align:right;
    width:90%;
    left:0%;
}
```

and it is placed inside the

```
.container{
    padding-top:4%;
    padding-left:6%;
    padding-bottom:4%;
    right:40%;
    width:88%;

}
```

Comment: the images are the same.

Comment: @y0hami sorry, changed it!

Comment: Can you provide the HTML for your page because the code you provided works for me http://i.imgur.com/fhc8Kzv.png

Comment: @y0hami I made a jsfiddle! https://jsfiddle.net/x4cq22tL/

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `right` as a position parameter, not `left`, and `.container` needs to have `position: relative` so that the absolute position of `#date` relates to it:

```
#date{
    border: 1px solid red;
    position:absolute;
    text-align:right;
    width:90%;
    right:0;
}

.container{
    position: relative;
    [...]
}
```

Comment: Tried it but it doesn't work, the bug in safari is still there. https://jsfiddle.net/x4cq22tL/